# Installing old app versions as beta tester for migration testing

Tags: google-developers-console, developer-console

In our app we updated the database from one version to another.
Now for testing I want to jump between older versions that were officially released at some point in time.

In the [Android developer console](https://play.google.com/console) we can find the previous releases under

`Production / Tab "Releases" / Section "Release history" / Dropdown "Show"`

and a direct installation link for internal testers under

`Blue rightarrow "Details" of the version to install / Section "App Bundles" / Blue rightarrow "Details" of the desired APK / Tab "Downloads" / Link "Copy Sharable link"`

The link looks like this:

```
https://play.google.com/apps/test/<name.of.my.app>/<release versionCode number>
```

Now if I open this link on my target device (where "Internal app sharing" is activated in the settings) one of two things can happen:

a) everything works fine:
Google offers me to install the old app version with the hint

> This version of this app (<versionCode number>) may be old. Turn off auto-update for this app to keep it from getting updated.

b) I get the following notification:

> You're an internal tester. This app may be unsecure or unstable.

In this case, the most recent version available to internal testers (typically the future version) is installed.

- I have several different Google accounts for alpha testers, and all of them are listed in the same group (Email list) under Testing / Internal testing / Testers
- All accounts are in "developer mode" in the Play store and have "Internal app sharing" active in the Play store settings
- I typically uninstall old app versions before clicking on the APK link which I sent to my tester accounts via Email
- I have several phones with various Android versions, screen sizes etc. I could not recognize a deterministic pattern for ending up in situation "b)"

How can I install the older versions when the second situation "b)" appears?